# ruby directory function

Tags: ruby, shared, directory

Here's the code :

```
Dir.foreach('C:\\Documents and Settings\\') { |entry|
    if File.directory?( entry )
        puts entry
    end
}

Dir.foreach('\\\\10.80.14.20\\transfer') { |entry|
    if File.directory?( entry )
        puts entry
    end
}
```

Both `C:\\Documents and Settings` and `\\10.80.14.20` contain directories.  But it only lists the folders under `C:\Documents and Settings`. While the folders under `\\\\10.80.14.20` isn't listed. It seems `File.directory?( entry )` cannot work under shared folders. Am I right? If so, is there any other methods to identify folders when under shared folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map `\\10.80.14.20\transfer` as a separate drive say `F:` on your machine where you're trying to run this program and then modify your code to

```
Dir.foreach('f:\\') { |entry|
    if File.directory?("f:\\#{entry}")
        puts entry
    end
}
```

However if you intend to run such code as a windows service, then you'll have to map the drive from within your code because windows services don't recognize externally mapped drives.

```
require 'win32ole'
def map_my_drive
    net = WIN32OLE.new('WScript.Network')
    user_name = "<your_domain>\\<your_user>"
    password = "<your_password>"
    net.MapNetworkDrive( 'f:', "\\\\10.80.14.20\\transfer", nil,  user_name, password )
end 

map_my_drive

Dir.foreach('f:\\') { |entry|
    if File.directory?("f:\\#{entry}")
        puts entry
    end
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But **File.directory?** doesn't work even I've mapped **\\10.80.14.20\transfer** as a separate drive.

Comment: you can change your code to use full path and it should work. `Dir.foreach('f:\\') {|entry| puts entry if File.directory?("f:\\#{entry}")}`

Answer (score 0):

If you can mount it to a local drive I suppose it will work with the standard `Dir.foreach` because the operating system will hide it for you.

If you cannot, then you could use the [Ruby/SMB](http://rubysmb.sourceforge.net/) library, I'm not sure it will work nowadays, but you could try other as well ([net-smb](https://github.com/fumiyas/ruby-net-smb)).

Example code (not tested):

```
require 'smb'

SMB::Dir.foreach('smb://10.80.14.20/transfer') do |entry|
  if entry.dir?
    puts entry
  end
end
```

Comment: My operating system is windows, so i didn't try if it will works if I mount it. I do try mapping the shared folder as a local drive. But It doesn't work either. I would like to try net-smb, but I failed to install it. It give me this error : checking for libsmbclient.h... no. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I meant mapping under mounting. You'll need the samba library to compile the net-smb module.